# What is the :< operator in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

[This blog post](http://dlaing.org/cofun/posts/free_and_cofree.html) uses the `:<` operator. What does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the blog post it's defined by the data declaration for the `Cofree` type:

```
data Cofree f a = a :< f (Cofree f a)
```

This makes `:<` an infix *data constructor*, which you can use to construct or to pattern match `Cofree` values.

That definition is also available in the [`Control.Comonad.Cofree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html) module of the `free` package on Hackage.

There's *another* frequently used definition of `:<` in the [`Data.Sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#g:6) module of the `containers` package, as a constructor for the `ViewL` type used to pattern match the left end of a sequence.